# Laravel Nova Override BelongsTo Language field based on already translated resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Imagine the following 3 models with fields:

```
Listing:
id

ListingTranslation:
id
listing_id
language_id
title

Language:
name
iso
```

Inside my `ListingTranslation` create/update form how can I filter the **language selector** to NOT SHOW the languages that have been already translated?

(i.e. If I have 2 languages ES (id 1) and EN (id 2) and if I have a listing with id 1 and this listing already has a listing_translation with id 1, listing_id 1 and language_id 1, the language selector should only show EN as an option).

**Language selector**:

```
BelongsTo::make('Language')
```

[Laravel Nova documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#relatable-filtering) provides the following method to filter the queries that are used to populate relationship model selection menus:

```
    public static function relatableQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
         return $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id);
    }
```

However, I do not know how to access something like listing_id from this method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating Nova resource for pivot table `ListingTranslation`, you can make use of `BelongsToMany` relation.

Under `Listing` Nova resource fields add `BelongsToMany::make('Languages')`. Assuming you have already defined the relationship in `Listing` model.

At this point when you attach a language which is already attached, you will see an error message `The language is already attached`

But if you still want to stop listing the already attached languages you can add `relatableQuery` given below under `Listing` nova resource.

```
public static function relatableLanguages(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $listing = $request->findResourceOrFail();

    return $query->whereNotIn('id', $listing->languages->pluck('id'));
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I need the relationship between Listing and ListingTranslation in order to retrieve available translations for given listing. Therefore, your relatableLanguage method should be in ListingTranslation resource. Do you know how to implement it in ListingTranslation?